# Optimizing load of big data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm working with a really big array in JS and I can see most of the time is used for loading and parsing the json data.
// is a Chrome Extension (but maybe I can move it to a nodejs app)

This is basically how I loading my data:

```
async function loadData(jsonFiles){
const fullData = [];
for(const jsonFile of jsonFiles){
    const localUrl = 'http://localhost/'+jsonFile;  
    const response = await fetch(jsonFile);
    if ( response.ok ){
                try{
                    const data = await response.json();
                    const L = data.length;
                    for (let k = 0; k < L; k++) {
                       
                       fullData.push(data[k]);
                        
                    }
                }
                catch(e){
                }
            }
}
return fullData;
}
```

Is there any faster way to do that? even if it implies to save the data in another way/format

Comment: @AndyRay It gathers all jsons to single array

Comment: A loop with `await` means you're doing all the `fetch`es serially. It can sometimes save a lot of time to let them run in parallel: like put the `fetch` promises in an array and then do a `await Promise.all(fetchArray)` on them.

Comment: @AndyRay - You can do the work in parallel.

Comment: It depends on what type of data you're working with, but you can use `TypedArrays` to store the data as ints or bytes which is smaller in file size than storing it as json so it should be faster when reading.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the `fetch` calls in parallel, but other than that there's not a lot more you can do:

```
function loadData(jsonFiles){
    return Promise.all(
        jsonFiles.map(async file => {
            const localUrl = 'http://localhost/'+jsonFile;  
            const response = await fetch(jsonFile);
            if (response.ok) {
                try{
                    return await response.json();
                } catch (e) {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        })
    ).then(results => {
        return results.filter(result => result); // Filter out the `null`s
    }).then(results => {
        return results.flat(); // Flatten the results into one array
    });
}
```

Comment: It the problem is parsing json parallelism won't help there, as JS is single-threaded.

Comment: @BeniaminH - We have no reason to believe JSON parsing dominates here, quite the reverse, network overhead probably dominates. Yes, the main UI thread is just one thread, but overlapping the network requests (which your answer also does) is helpful.

Comment: but if I request them in parallel then they will be received with no specific order right? is a sorted array and also I need a fallback (if response.ok==false I need to make another call to another URL)

Comment: I've tested serial vs parallel requests and is a bit faster in parallel (not sure if the final result is sorted) but the difference in speed is not so important, so I guess the bottleneck is the json parse

Comment: @Enrique - *"but if I request them in parallel then they will be received with no specific order right?"* They may be *received* in no specific order, but `Promise.all` keeps track of the order of what you passed it and passes you the results in that same order. If you ask for A, B, C, D, and E, you'll get the results in that order regardless of what order the result arrived in.

Comment: @Enrique ofcourse in your test example the bottleneck is json.parse because you test it on localhost :). You can try use somting like this [greenlet](https://github.com/developit/greenlet)

Answer (score 1):

Make call and transform to json parallel

```js
  async function loadData(jsonFiles){
    const calls = [];
    for(const jsonFile of jsonFiles){
      calls.push(fetch(jsonFile).then(response => response.json()));
    }

   return await Promise.allSettled(calls)
       .then(parts => parts.filter(({status}) => status === "fulfilled"))
       .then(parts => parts.map(({value}) => value))
       .then(parts => parts.flat());
  }
```